# Adjective describing a room where when little fresh air left

Tags: word-request

Imagine a room, for example a classroom, where many people have been sitting and listening to their teacher for two hours while no windows is open or no air-conditioner like machine works.So as you can guess the fresh air in the room getting less and less gradually and the  odor in the room turns to be a bit bad odor because of lacking fresh air or oxygen.

What are the adjective we can use to describing this room.

For example :

> Coming into the classroom I felt it was..........So I asked if they
>   would mind if I opened the window.

Comment: I'd go with "stuffy".

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/5332/how-would-i-describe-a-room-with-no-ventilation

Answer (score 5):

The word you are looking for is *stuffy*:

> (of a place) lacking fresh air or ventilation.
>   "a stuffy, overcrowded office"

Comment: Or, if it's also quite warm, you could say "stifling"

Comment: Or, if the people all left, the room was sealed so no new oxygen could get in and you came back the next day to the lingering odors, _"stale."_

Answer (score 1):

I think you would describe that room as hot, sweaty and stuffy.  Also there might not be enough water to drink and you could be really thirsty.  "Open the window please, it's too stuffy in here", for example.